# Angular.js template won't show on angular-route url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I am trying to learn angular.js and I want to load a form html through angular-route with a template.

I think I set up everything correctly, but the html form won't load on the url that I set on config.  And the other config url I set up for testing won't work either.
Here is the code

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="EventPlanner">
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular/ng_config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular/ng_controller.js"></script>
```

ng_config.js

```
angular.module("EventPlanner", ["ngRoute"])
.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl: "template/register.html"
    })
    .when("/make_plan", {
        template: "<h1>make plans</h1>"
    });
}]);
```

ng_controller.js

```
angular.module("EventPlanner", [])
    .controller("registerControl", [function(){
        var self = this;
        self.submit = function(){
            location.href = "#/make_plan";
        };
    }]);
```

register.html

```
<div class="main container">
<div class="row" ng-controller="registerControl as regi">
    <form ng-submit="regi.submit()" name="regiForm" class="register col-xs-12">
        <label class="col-xs-12" for="name">
            <span class="col-xs-2">Name</span>
            <input ng-model="regi.username" class="col-xs-5" type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
            <span class="col-xs-5" ng-show="regiForm.name.$error.required">This feild is required</span>
        </label>
        <label class="col-xs-12" for="email">
            <span class="col-xs-2">Email</span><input ng-model="regi.email" class="col-xs-5" type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
            <span class="col-xs-5" ng-show="regiForm.email.$error.required">This feild is required</span>
        </label>
        <label class="col-xs-12" for="birthday">
            <span class="col-xs-2">Birthday</span><input ng-model="regi.birthday" class="col-xs-5"  type="date" id="birthday">
        </label>
        <label class="col-xs-12" for="password">
            <span class="col-xs-2">Password</span>
            <input ng-model="regi.password" class="col-xs-5" type="password" id="password" name="password"
            ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,16}$/" ng-minlength="6" ng-maxlength="16" required>

        </label>
        <ul class="col-xs-7">
            <li class="col-xs-12" ng-show="regiForm.password.$error.pattern">Must contain one lower &amp; uppercase letter, and one non-alpha character (a number or a symbol.)</li>
            <li class="col-xs-12" ng-show="regiForm.password.$error.minlength">Password Must be more than 5 characters</li>
            <li class="col-xs-12" ng-show="regiForm.password.$error.maxlength">Password Must be less than 20 characters</li>

            <li class="col-xs-12" ng-show="regiForm.name.$dirty && regiForm.name.$error.required">Please enter name
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="col-xs-7 no-padding">
            <button type="submit" ng-disabled="regiForm.$invalid" class="btn">Submit</button>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

I have been looking at the code over and over for past few days, I cannot figure out what I did wrong.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: what is the url you are typing on the browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your code.

ng_config.js

```
angular.module("EventPlanner", ["ngRoute"]) // correct!
.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl: "template/register.html"
    })
    .when("/make_plan", {
        template: "<h1>make plans</h1>"
    });
}]);
```

The above is correct, you are defining a new module 'EventPlanner' and defining an array of dependencies.

ng_controller.js

```
angular.module("EventPlanner", []) // incorrect!!
    .controller("registerControl", [function(){
        var self = this;
        self.submit = function(){
            location.href = "#/make_plan";
        };
    }]);
```

The above is **incorrect**. You do not need to pass an empty array anymore as you have already created your module 'EventPlanner'.

What is actually happening above is you are redefining the module 'EventPlanner' and overwriting your previous declaration.

Change ng_controller.js to the following:

```
angular.module("EventPlanner") // fixed
    .controller("registerControl", [function(){
        var self = this;
        self.submit = function(){
            location.href = "#/make_plan";
        };
    }]);
```

Now, when ng_controller.js is parsed, it tells angular that it wishes to create a 'registerController' for a previously defined module called 'EventPlanner'. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: A suggestion: once you've got to grips with angular-route, I would recommend you look into using AngularUI Router [link](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/) instead, as recommended on John Papa's excellent style guide [link](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y270).

Comment: Thank you so much.  This is a great advice!. You are the best.